# create groups of rows in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create 200 clusters of data from a list of cells.

In my case, i have 1900 rows of data and i want to divide them in 200 equal groups.

How can i do that?

There should be 9 or 10 rows in every group.

What i need is a cell indicating me in what group number a certain row is.

So it should look something like this

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
```

etc… until 200 groups on 1900 rows

Comment: 1900 / 200 = 9.5.  Does it matter which half of the groups have 9 rows and which half have 10 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the group number, use `=TRUNC((ROW()-1)/YourGroupSize)+1`

For the number within the group, use `=MOD(ROW()-1,YourGroupSize)+1`

Note: If you have a header row, replace the `-1` with `-2`.

For this example, I used a `YourGroupSize` of 4

```
Row  Grp Sub   
 1   1   1
 2   1   2
 3   1   3
 4   1   4
 5   2   1
 6   2   2
 7   2   3
 8   2   4
 9   3   1
10   3   2
11   3   3
12   3   4
13   4   1
```

Comment: for what i understand this creates a number of groups with a fixed number of rows in every group (for example 4). What i need is the opposite of this, i need it to create exactly 200 groups (on my 1900 rows) with an equal split of rows between every group

Comment: Oh perfect i did it. I used your formula and inserting in YourGroupSize 9.5 it created 200 groups. Thanks!

Comment: When using a non-integer YourGroupSize, your groups will alternate between 9 items and 10 items.  You might want to throw a TRUNC() around the second formula as it'll have some items with decimals.

Answer (score 0):

A double loop should be able to do this, if I understood the problem correctly.

```
Public Sub Group()
k = 1
For j = 1 To 90
    For i = 0 To 10
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + k, 1) = j
    Next i
     k = k + 10
Next j
End Sub
```